# VB on restore event

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I know there is an event for when the size changes, but is there an event when I restore the window (click on the taskbar after it has been minimized). This is visual basic 2010. Im new to visual basic, though I do know C and java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not persay you will need to generate something conditionally. Two things I can think of. The first is to handle the [`Activated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.activated.aspx) event for the Form and test if the `WindowState` is Minimized if so then do what you want to. The other would be to override the [`OnLocationChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.onlocationchanged.aspx) Method Checking for `WindowState` also.

```
Private Sub Form1_Activated(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Activated
    If WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
        'Your Code here
    End If
End Sub
```

or

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnLocationChanged(e As System.EventArgs)
    If WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
        'Your Code here
    End If
    MyBase.OnLocationChanged(e)
End Sub
```